# Why does toString of PriorityQueue returns elements out of order?

Tags: java, priority-queue

I have this simple code using PriorityQueue where I want integers to be stored in decreasing order.

```java
PriorityQueue<Integer> jumps = new PriorityQueue<>(20,Collections.reverseOrder());
jumps.add(8);
jumps.add(5);
jumps.add(15);
jumps.add(2);
jumps.add(16);
System.out.println(jumps.toString());
```

This prints

```
[16, 15, 8, 2, 5]
```

while I would have expected

```
[16, 15, 8, 5, 2]
```

What am I doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The order returned by the `Iterator` of a `PriorityQueue` is [not guaranteed](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) (emphasis theirs):

> The Iterator provided in method `iterator()` [...] [is] *not* guaranteed to traverse the elements of the priority queue in any particular order. If you need ordered traversal, consider using `Arrays.sort(pq.toArray())`.

This is [what `toString()` uses](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#toString()), therefore the order of the elements in the `toString()` output is also not specified

What **is** guaranteed is that multiple calls to [`poll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Queue.html#poll()) will return the values in the appropriate order:

```
while (!jumps.isEmpty()) {
  System.out.println(jumps.poll());
}
```

Comment: Ok , so PriorityQueue behaves as is expected. it is just that the toString invokes Iterator which does not order guarantee. Thanks!

Comment: @rajeshnair You want to observe the output of `toString()` after each call to `poll()`, and look at its implementation.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel ,  I have used PriorityQueue extensively and am aware of the implementation. Just was confused when I saw this output. I should have explored more before posting the question